# Granting access to a new host?

Tags: azure, ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine

I have a Ubuntu VM running on Azure, which I want to access from a Linux host.  I've created ssh keys on that host.  how do I add these keys to the VM in Azure? ideally from the portal?

I can't seem to find any docs to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you created the instance first with username and pwd I suppose and now you want to access it using certificates. There is phrase for that "this isn't how it works, this isn't how any of it works". Ideally you should create your vms with the authentication type as ssh public key and copy paste the ssh public key (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-use-ssh-key/)

At this stage however you can configure it custom - follow this article and setup ssh with key in your server http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-linux-unix/

Comment: actually, I had created with an ssh public key.  the problem was I didn't have access to that key so I was hoping I could do it from the portal.  once I got hold of the key I could add to the known_hosts file.  but thanks for the reply